# Where on the web can I find a Stratum protocol specification document?

Tags: mining-pools, bitcoin-core-development, stratum

I am writing my own mining pool server for Bitcoin and would like to work with a detailed and complete specification document for the Stratum protocol.  There are documents on the web that casually outline the protocol (https://braiins.com/stratum-v1/docs and https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Stratum_mining_protocol) but I am looking for something rigorous and complete and wasn't able to find it.  The reference documentation of BIP 41 and 40 doesn't exist (see [Where is BIP 40 and 41?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/114168/where-is-bip-40-and-41/114169#114169)).  Something like this is good: https://github.com/aeternity/protocol/blob/master/STRATUM.md

Answer (score 1):

The team at Braiins is working on [Stratum v2](https://braiins.com/stratum-v2) in collaboration with others. There have been a number of [changes](https://braiins.com/upgrade/compare-mining-protocols#compare) made since Stratum v1 was first specified.

There is a work in progress specification for Stratum v2 [here](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1FadCWj-57dvhxsnFM_7X806qyvhR0u3i85607bGHxvg/edit).

Comment: I need the specs for V1 as I'm working with miners from 2019

Comment: @andrewz: I asked on Twitter and the Braiins link you included in your question is the closest thing that exists apparently https://twitter.com/michaelfolkson/status/1539217254709178368?s=20&t=QB7Sc9dmqtsd9-V7OXM-vQ